# Iphone : detecting drag / swipe direction starting from a button

Tags: iphone, drag, swipe

I trying to make a swipe mechanism for a view that might have buttons on it.  Without a button its a piece of cake.

However if your finger starts on the button, you can trigger an event (drag outside) but that does not tell me the direction.

So how can I detect the direction of a swipe / drag where your fingers starts on a button?

Any ideas?

Thanks Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still easy you just don't use the drag outside event. Look at the `hitTest:withEvent` in UIView to determine if it starts in the button or not. Along with UISwipeGestureRecognizer (or the touch event stuff) you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes UISwipeGestureRecognizer worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check out `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. You ought to be able to just add it to your main view and have it recognize the gesture whether or not it originates on a button.